# ModRewrite Oddity

Tags: php, apache, redirect

This is very odd to me, I'm trying to pretty much redefine a SEO redirect but something odd is happening.  The urls that end with /test/test/ and /test/test33 etc work but if I have a url that ends with /test/ it works but /test33 doesn't, am I missing something?  In summary first second and fourth rules work, but the third doesn't.  If there is a better way I'm open to anything.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^.*(media/|\.php).*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)$     /asports/$1/$2.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/$    /asports/$1/$2/index.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$          /asports/$1.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$         /asports/$1/index.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^$              /asports/index.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/$             /asports/index.php [QSA]
```

Comment: define "doesn't work" i would have chosen a different ordering...

Comment: people , please use router scripts ! there is no reason you cant do that even with the crappiest code to maintain. No wonder why Rails or Django folks get things right ... Got legacy code ? use buffers inside router callbacks.